# John The Ripper does not load password hash, how can I fix it?

Tags: passwords, hash, md5, john-the-ripper

I want to crack a specific hash password with JTR:

```
48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d
```

I put this hash in a txt file like this:

```
echo '48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d' > hash.txt
```

and I run JTR in this way:

```
john hash.txt --format=md5crypt --wordlist=/Users/ludo/Documents/TryHackMe/Dizionari/rockyou.txt
```

The result of John is:

```
ludo@MinidiLudovico CrackTheHash % ls hash.txt 
ludo@MinidiLudovico CrackTheHash % john hash.txt --format=md5crypt --wordlist=/Users/ludo/Documents/TryHackMe/Dizionari/rockyou.txt        
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ) 
ludo@MinidiLudovico CrackTheHash %
```

I'm sure that the password is in the rockyou.txt file because it is `easy`, and I'm sure that the password was hashed in MD5.

Comment: And you looked up the FAQ and tried the things there? Like `--show` and adding a line break to the hash?

Comment: If you want to crack raw md5, shouldn't the format be `raw-md5` instead of `md5crypt`?

Comment: @schroeder that's all the output you get, apart from possibly a line saying that it's using UTF-8 for input encoding. Much as I like John, it's output is not very helpful when you're trying to work out this kind of issue.

Comment: `No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)` is the ***full*** output? I seriously doubt that ...  john tends to pump out quite a lot of text as it runs. If I am wrong, then you need to run it in a more verbose mode ...

Comment: I posted a couple things 4 hours ago and I'm still wondering if you've tried them. `--show`, in case the hash has already been cracked, and adding a line break to the hash file.

Comment: it does not accept --show. John answer that --show does not exist

Comment: What machine are you using for this? Are you on a CTF box? What's the version of john? Can you run it in a more verbose mode? That is not the normal output of john. Something is going on.

Comment: I'm using a mac mini m1 with macOS 12.1, my john version is 1.9.0 and I installed it with homebrew and I can't run it in verbose mode cause there isn't any parmeter to do it. (--verbosity=6) does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but there is a sort of problem with John the Ripper, I uninstalled it with:

```
brew uninstall john
```

And I install another version of it named john-jumbo.

```
brew install john-jumbo
```

Now it works perfectly.

Ps.  `--format=md5crypt` doesn't work with my hash so I used `--format=raw-md5`.

Comment: Yes, this was in the FAQ. raw-md5 format is in the larger, more complete version of john, but it should have worked without specifying the format, too.

Comment: I still think you had oriiginally installed a strange version because it was behaving in a non-standard manner.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct format for an md5crypt hash. They typically start with `$1$` - you can see examples of the various md5crypt formats that John accepts in the [source code](https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/src/MD5_fmt.c#L51). When John reads your input file (`hash.txt`), you're telling it to only look for hashes in the md5crypt format - so it ignores the line in the file because it's not formatted correctly.

Your hash is just plain MD5, so you need to use `--format=raw-md5` instead of `--format=md5crypt`

Comment: If I put --format=raw-md5 the result is:
Unknown ciphertext format name requested

Comment: Also if I run 'john hash.txt', and I don't put the md5crypt format it gives me the same output. 'No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)'

Comment: If your version of John doesn't support `raw-md5` it must be a strange or broken build. Use the version on [GitHub](https://github.com/openwall/john), or check what formats your version supports.

Comment: You don't need to go to the source code to see the correct inputs for the hashes. They are in the documentation: https://openwall.info/wiki/john/hash-formats

Comment: @schroeder that page hasn't been updated since 2012, and is missing many of the currently supported formats (and also several variants of md5crypt, such as the `$apr1$` or `{smd5}` formats).

Comment: `raw-md5` may not be in the version the OP is using. "As of John the Ripper version 1.8.0, valid "format names" are descrypt, bsdicrypt, md5crypt, bcrypt, LM, AFS, tripcode, dummy, and crypt" From the FAQ: "That is, you normally only need to use "--format" when John would otherwise misdetect your hash/cipher type (e.g., when it says LM and you know that your hashes are in fact raw MD5, you'd use "--format=raw-md5" with -jumbo)"

Comment: Granted, and yet, it has the md5crypt format. And it is easier to read than source code ...